# One to Many relashionship with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-core

in my project (Asp.net Core Web Api) I have the tables "Truck" and "UserAccount with a one to many relashionship.

```
[Table("UserAccount")]
public class UserAccount : BaseClass
{
    // Foreign Keys
    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserAccountType))]
    public int UserAccountTypeId { get; set; } 
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Gender))]
    public int GenderId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Truck))]
    public int TruckId { get; set; }

    // Properties
   
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
   
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
    //public virtual Truck Truck { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual UserAccountType UserAccountType { get; set; }
    
    public Truck Truck { get; set; }
}

[Table("Truck")]
public class Truck : BaseClass
{
    // Foreign Keys

    // Properties
    
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Column(Order = 4)]
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 5)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 6)]
    public string VATNumber { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual ICollection<TruckFoodType> TruckFoodTypes { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TruckOption> TruckOptions { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

In the method OnModelCreation into my ApplicationDbContex file I have this to create the one to many relashionship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
            .HasOne<Truck>(u => u.Truck)
            .WithMany(t => t.UserAccounts)
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.TruckId);
```

But when I try to populate the UserAccount table I have this error message :
"Merge instruction is in conflict with "FK_User_Account_TruckId". This conflict occurse in the database xxx table dbo.Truck column Id" (Sorry, Comes from a french translation)

I don't hunderstand why.
Can somebody help me?
Thanks

Comment: Feel free to write that as an answer and accept accordingly. Others might find your mistake helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, stupid mistake. In some cases the TruckId field from the User Account table can be null. So I added a "?" to this fields like this : `public int? TruckId { get; set; }` Sorry for inconvenience